# Right way to remove punctuation and white spaces in word from string

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have a String, for example: `"h e l l o, world! ! am gl@d to see    you!".`
And I want to get a result like this (remove punctuation, other symbols and white spaces): `"hello, world! am gld to see you!"`
In what way can I implement this?

I tried splitting string into words with this code, but it doesn't handle white spaces in words and punctuation on the right places.

```
String[] words = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: The question is too broad. You have to first write down the list of rules. *You* have to do that, we can't do it for you. E.g. since `@` can be an `a`, can `3` be an `e`? Can `!` be an `l` (letter `L`)?

Comment: @Andreas, sorry, I meant, every not letter symbol just has to be removed => gl@d == gld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of code to make the change.

```
String s = "h e l l o, world! ! am gl@d to see    you!";
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\b\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L}\\b)", ""); // remove spaces separating single letters
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+(?=\\P{L})", ""); // remove spaces before non-letters
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("(\\P{L})\\1+", "$1"); // remove repeated non-letters
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("@", "a"); // replace '@' with 'a'
System.out.println(s);
```

*Output*

```
h e l l o, world! ! am gl@d to see    you!
hello, world! ! am gl@d to see    you!
hello, world!! am gl@d to see you!
hello, world! am gl@d to see you!
hello, world! am glad to see you!
```

Comment: Oh, but it doesn't work for text like this: "h   e l l o". If there's more than one space before letter.

Comment: @Twinkle_Monkey Change `)\\s(` to `)\\s+(` to remove multiple spaces separating single letters.